# How to update MySQL with CentOS 6 in most unintrusive way - in regard to perl and PHP packages?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

For my few hobby projects (web games + forums) I have been using CentOS 5 (then 6) with Drupal and PostgreSQL plus few custom PHP and Perl scripts written by mysef.

Since PostgreSQL version delivered with CentOS package has been a bit dated, I always used [the PGDG packages](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php):

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i pgdg

pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch
postgresql93-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.i686
postgresql93-libs-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.i686
postgresql93-server-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.i686
```

As a web developer this has been a very pleasant experience, since (by some great magic) all the other CentOS packages (like php-pgsql and perl-DBD-Pg) just worked with the PGDG packages.

Now I have decided to switch to WordPress for my new projects and am forced to switch the database too:

I have to use MySQL or MariaDB with CentOS 6.5.

So my question is: if anybody can recommend a similarly comfortable package repository for MySQL/MariaDB - which wouldn't mess up any other CentOS packages and which would update itself (with `yum update`)?

And please do not suggest something like Fedora or EPEL repositories, because other than for MySQL/MariaDB I would like not to add any additional packages to have my server as "stable" as possible.

Comment: My question is about installation which is a part of **Database Administration** and thus perfectly ontopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For Official MySQL packages: [Oracle yum repository for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/).
- For MariaDB Packages: [MariaDB yum repository](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/getting-installing-and-upgrading-mariadb/mariadb-binary-packages/installing-mariadb-rpm-files/installing-mariadb-with-yum/).

After that, you will be able to update MySQL via yum up to the latest stable version. They only include the server, client and the minimal MySQL libraries.

For details, I've recently written a step-by-step guide on [How to install MySQL 5.6 on CentoOS 7](http://dbahire.com/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-on-centos-7/) (most of it applies to CentOS 6, except for the initial rpm version and the start commands). It is a very common task because Red Hat/CentOS has very ancient versions of MySQL (and PostgreSQL).